# Word/phrase to describe that a path is in the way of two frequented routes?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Is the phrase "along the way" or "in passing"? Example sentence:

> Mark didn't know why Marta had gone to that strange place. It
>   didn't/wasn't __ her university to her house.

Comment: Another way could be to say, "It wasn't on the way for her between her university and her house."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using [**en route**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/en+route):

> Mark didn't know why Marta had gone to that strange place. It **wasn't en route to** her university or to her house.

En route is [defined by The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/en+route) as:

> on or along the way; on the road